# Deleting external drive with healthy (primary partition) through cmd is not working

Tags: command-line, partitioning

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/djhK3.png]

This is the method that I followed as answered in this question: [Cannot delete partition in diskpart - invalid argument?](https://superuser.com/questions/728486/cannot-delete-partition-in-diskpart-invalid-argument/728501#728501?newreg=7e5364488252413499ac04a4eb8da4b0)

Comment: Does `clean` work? It should demolish every partition on the selected disk. Does Disk Management (`diskmgmt.msc`) work?